# How to get the screen brightness in python on a windows laptop?

Tags: python, wmi

I'm creating a program to set my keyboard and mouse brightness according to my screen brightness.
The issue is that I don't know how to get my screen brightness (I know that i can set my screen brightness with this line:
`wmi.WMI(namespace='wmi').WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods()[0].WmiSetBrightness(desired_brightness, 0)`)

But I want to know how to get the brightness instead of changing it.
Maybe I can use one of the windows dlls with ctypes or maybe I can do this with wmi but i don't really understand how it works.

If you have any idea on how to do that, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `WmiMonitorBrightness()[0]`.Like:

```
import wmi

print(wmi.WMI(namespace='wmi').WmiMonitorBrightness()[0])
```

This has the same result with my device:

[image]